# Natural sorting in Shiny DT (datatables) doesn't work

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

Dear Shiny and DT masters!
I'm trying to use natural sorting plugin in my shiny app, but it doesn't seem to work. I think it was working with previous version of Shiny or/and before DT package. Can anybody help me? See my example below (I'm trying to sort the last column):

server.R

```
library(shiny)
require(DT)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$example <- DT::renderDataTable({
        table = cbind(LETTERS[1:5],matrix(1:20,nrow=5),c(1,2,3,10,"a"))
        table = rbind(c("filtered",round(rnorm(5),3)),table)
        DT::datatable(table,
                      rownames = FALSE,
                      extensions = list(FixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 1)),
                      options = list(
                          columnDefs = list(list(type = "natural", targets = "_all"))))
    })
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
require(DT)
shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
        tags$head(
            tags$script(src = "http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js", type = "text/javascript"),
            tags$script(src = "http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/sorting/natural.js", type = "text/javascript")
        ),
        DT::dataTableOutput('example')
    )
)
```

Comment: Doesn't look like your initial table loads properly.

Comment: Sorry, typing error, but the idea remains the same...

Comment: Sorting on all the columns is working perfectly for me. Is there any error or warning showing up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [current development version](https://github.com/rstudio/DT) of **DT** (>= 0.1.16), you can enable this plug-in using `datatable(..., plugins = 'natural')`, e.g.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput('example')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$example <- DT::renderDataTable({
      table = cbind(LETTERS[1:5],matrix(1:20,nrow=5),c(1,2,3,10,"a"))
      table = rbind(c("filtered",round(rnorm(5),3)),table)
      table
    }, server = FALSE, plugins = 'natural', options = list(
      columnDefs = list(list(type = "natural", targets = "_all"))
    ))
  }
)
```

See [the documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/plugins.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, you guys are really making progress! But, on our server, we are working with really huge tables (of course we're using `Scroller`), so we would like to NOT use `server = FALSE`. But it doesn't work with `= TRUE`.

Comment: @user1991825 Unfortunately this plug-in was not designed for the server-side processing mode. To implement natural sorting for `server = TRUE` may be a little involved, but you can file a feature request to https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues anyway. I'll see if it is possible when I have got more time.